# ObjectGears service does not start

Tags: windows-services, objectgears

I have downloaded free ObjectGears version and installed it. However, the service does not start after installing. I can see in the event log this:

Exception code:0xc00000fd
Failing application: \WinService\ObjectGearsServiceFree.exe
Event name: APPCRASH

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be probably in a erroneous configuration of the objectgearsservice.config.

Check please if it is a valid XML. Check also database connectionstring do database a make sure the service is running under account that is database owner of the database specified in the connection string.